# set delegate of tableview to another class with swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, delegates

I want to set the delegate of tableview to another custom class  in a UITableViewController,
It's ok with objectC,but get an error with Swift,detail as following images.
old objectC code is here:https://github.com/ninjinkun/NJKScrollFullScreen

1、OK in ObjectC:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIViewController+NJKFullScreenSupport.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *data;
@property (nonatomic) NJKScrollFullScreen *scrollProxy;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _scrollProxy = [[NJKScrollFullScreen alloc] initWithForwardTarget:self]; // UIScrollViewDelegate and UITableViewDelegate methods proxy to ViewController

    self.tableView.delegate = (id)_scrollProxy; // cast for surpress incompatible warnings

    _scrollProxy.delegate = self;
}
....
@end
```

2、Error in Swift，I think maybe it's type convert problem:
error: [see error](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1pJqgUZT)

```
class GLBaseTableViewController : UITableViewController,NJKScrollFullscreenDelegate{
var dataSource = []
var scrollProxy:NJKScrollFullScreen!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollProxy = NJKScrollFullScreen(forwardTarget: self)
    self.tableView.delegate = scrollProxy
    scrollProxy.delegate = self
}
```

3、Delegate ob：

```
@protocol NJKScrollFullscreenDelegate;

@interface NJKScrollFullScreen : NSObject<UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<NJKScrollFullscreenDelegate> delegate;
```